# Why does this ArrayList not retain it's value unless it is static?

Tags: android, static, android-volley

So, I've got the following code that hits up a database for some info:

```
// This is the arraylist I am talking about
private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

private String getAllSongsScriptUrl =
    "https://songs-list-site-test.herokuapp.com/get_songs_list.php";

private RequestQueue requestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_songs);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    // Prepare the list to display the results
    ArrayList<String> results = getAllSongsFromDatabase();
    resultsListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results
    );
    Log.d("fuck", results.toString());
    resultsList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.songs_list_view);
    resultsList.setAdapter(resultsListAdapter);
}

private ArrayList<String> getAllSongsFromDatabase()
{
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, getAllSongsScriptUrl,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
            {
                try
                {
                    JSONArray songs = response.getJSONArray("songs");
                    for(int i = 0; i < songs.length(); i++)
                    {
                        // Get the data from the JSON response
                        JSONObject song = songs.getJSONObject(i);
                        String artist = song.getString("artist");
                        String song_name = song.getString("name");

                        // Construct a result string and add it to listview
                        String result =
                        artist.toString() +
                        " - " +
                        song_name.toString();
                        results.add(result);
                        // POINT A: Printing results works fine here
                    }
                }
                catch(JSONException e)
                {
                    // TODO: Handle
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {
                // TODO: Handle
            }
        }
    );
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    // POINT B, where things start to go pear shaped
    return results;
}
```

If I print the value of results at comment marked POINT A, I get a filled arraylist as expected. However, if I print the results at POINT B, I get an empty arraylist.

Not being one to give up easily, I fiddled with the code, trying to get it to work. I noticed, interestingly, that if I marked `results` as `static`, everything seems to work. WHY?

Comment: `requestQueue.add()` is queuing an _asynchronous_ task. At POINT B, that `ArrayList` hasn't been filled yet.

Comment: Okay, so how do I fix this?

Comment: You need to initialize your listview in onResponse(JSONObject response) this method, so once you got response then your arraylist filled and it will refelected on your listview

Comment: Don't return anything from `getAllSongsFromDatabase()`, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter` when your loop is done in `onResponse()`.

Comment: Brilliant, love you. Literally debugging this at 1AM, you're the best.

Comment: No problem. Btw, you might wanna move the JSON processing off the main thread eventually, especially if the results are sizeable, but that's a different topic. :-) Cheers!